# Given function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:f(x)=\cos x$, check which properties it has

Tags: functions

> Given function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}:f(x)=\cos x$, check whether it is
>
> 1. surjective
> 2. injective
> 3. increasing
> 4. decreasing
> 5. strictly increasing
> 6. strictly decreasing

*My Idea:*

$f(0)=f(2\pi)$ but $0 \neq 2\pi$ this f is not one one

consider $y=2 \in \mathbb{R}$

There does not exist any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\cos x=y=2$

then $f$ is not onto

what about other options

Comment: None of the above !

Comment: @DeepSea..can you give some counter exampels.thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f'(\pi/2)=-1<0$ and $f'(-\pi/2)=1>0$. $f$ is thus not increasing, decreasing, strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Indeed, it has *none* of the six listed properties.

Answer (score 0):

Infact if it is strictly increasing or decreasing then function must be one one because we can do ordering between real numbers .